# Get conditional SUM in first row

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, t-sql, view

I have table =>

```
Main Table  : MT
================
PK SPK Name D1 
==============
1, 0, XYZ, 0
1, 1, A, 99
1, 2, B, 88
1, 3, C, 77
2, 0, NULL, 0
2, 1, NULL, 99
2, 2, Z, 88
```

From that I want to get

```
Result Table  : RT
================
PK SPK Name D1 
==============
1, 0, XYZ, 264
1, 1, A, 99
1, 2, B, 88
1, 3, C, 77
2, 0, NULL, 187
2, 1, NULL, 99
2, 2, Z, 88
```

I want SUM of D1 in first row for each PK where SPK=0 instead of 0.

Also, D1 is always 0 where SPK=0. I want to display SUM in D1 fields where SPK=0 based on PK value.

**Any way to get the SUM of D1 in first row instead of 0 where SPK=0?**

Comment: I do not know how to do it. Thanks for your answer in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ranking function (sqlserver 2005+)

```
select PK, SPK, Name,
case when SPK = 0 then sum(D1) over (partition by pk)
else D1 end as D1
from table
order by PK, SPK
```

Comment: thank you. it is the best way n simple when having more columns.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 
    t.pk, 
    t.spk, 
    t.name, 
    CASE WHEN t.spk = 0 THEN ts.d1 ELSE t.d1 END AS d1
FROM your_table t
LEFT JOIN ( 
        SELECT tt.pk, SUM(tt.d1) AS d1 
        FROM your_table tt 
        GROUP BY tt.pk 
    ) ts ON t.pk = ts.pk
```

Comment: Nice one. Just remove the `LEFT`, it is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

```
select PK, SPK, Name,
  case when SPK = 0 then ( select Sum( D1 ) from ThineTable where PK = TT.PK )
    else D1 end as D1
  from ThineTable as TT
  order by PK, SPK
```